# How to do an image upload from an Android app to a Jboss Seam with IceFaces web app through multipart post?

Tags: android, upload, seam, icefaces, multipart

We need to upload images from our android app to our web app through HTTP POST.
There's tons of examples on the Android side... but I can't seem to find a simple and/or working example for Jboss Seam with Icefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Apache httpmime.jar It provides an MultipartEntity that allows you to give it a file to upload.  The api is pretty strait forward.

see http://hc.apache.org/user-docs.html